# Wordpress development using Vite+Docker+pug

Tags: php, wordpress, vite

I want to compile pug files using vite.js and update php files in a WordPress theme that is set up using docker-compose. Furthermore, I want to monitor the php files for changes and automatically reload them. However, even when the contents of the pug files are reflected in the php files, the automatic reload does not happen.

## file structure

```
my_project/
├── dist/
│   ├── wp-content/
│       ├── themes/
│           ├── test/
|               ├── assets/
|               |   ├── images/
|               |   ├── js/
|               |   |   └── app.js
|               |   └── css/
|               |       └── app.css
|               ├── index.php
|               └── style.css
├── mysql_data/
├── node_modules/
├── public/
├── src/
|   ├── pug/
|   |   └── index.pug
|   ├── scss/
|   |   ├── foundations/
|   |   ├── layouts/
|   |   ├── objects/
|   |   |   ├── components/
|   |   |   └── projects/
|   |   └──app.scss
|   └── js/
|       ├── modules/
|       └── app.js
├── .env
├── docker-compose.yml
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── vite.config.js
```

## vite.config.js

host:http://localhost:3000

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import pug from 'pug';
import pugPhpFilter from 'pug-php-filter';
import fs from 'fs';
import { Glob, glob } from 'glob';
import liveReload from 'vite-plugin-live-reload';
import path, { resolve } from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env') });

const proxyPath = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8000' : '';
const dist = './dist/wp-content/themes/' + process.env.WP_THEME;

export default defineConfig({
  root: './',
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'pugPhp',
      //apply: "serve",
      handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
        if ( file.endsWith('.pug') ) {
          console.log(`Pug file updated: ${file}`);
          const compiled = pug.compileFile(file, {
            pretty: true,
            filters: {
              php: pugPhpFilter
            }
          });
          const output = compiled();
          const srcPath = path.relative(path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pug'), file);
          const phpFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, dist, srcPath).replace(/\.pug$/, '.php');
          fs.writeFileSync(phpFilePath, output);
          //server.ws.send({ type: "full-reload", path: "*" });
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'phpUpdated',
      handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
        if ( file.endsWith('.php') ) {
          console.log(`PHP file updated: ${file}`);
          //server.ws.send({ type: "full-reload", path: "*" });
        }
      }
    },
    liveReload(__dirname+'/dist/wp-content/themes/'+process.env.WP_THEME+'/**/*.php'),
  ],
  build: {
    //outDir: path.resolve(__dirname, dist),
    manifest: true,
    //outDir: dist,
    assetsDir: "",
    emptyOutDir: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'src/js/app.js',
    },
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/': proxyPath,
    },
    cors: true,
    strictPort: true,
    port: 3000,
    host: true,
    hmr: {
      host: 'localhost'
    },
  },
});
```

## WordPress

host:http://localhost:8000

### functions.php

```
<?php

define('IS_VITE_DEVELOPMENT', true);

// load setting about vite
include "inc/inc.vite.php";

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
  $ver = "0";

  wp_enqueue_script( 'js', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/app.js' ), array(), $ver, true );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/app.css', array(), $ver );
});
```

## inc.vite.php

```
<?php

define('JS_DEPENDENCY', array());
define('JS_LOAD_IN_FOOTER', true); 

define('VITE_SERVER', 'http://localhost:3000');
define('VITE_ENTRY_POINT', '/../../../../../main.js');

//enqueue hook
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  $b = 1;
    
  if (IS_VITE_DEVELOPMENT === true) {

      // insert hmr into head for live reload
      function vite_head_module_hook() {
          echo '<script type="module" crossorigin src="' . VITE_SERVER . VITE_ENTRY_POINT . '"></script>';
      }
      add_action('wp_head', 'vite_head_module_hook');        

  } else {
     // Production Server Configuration
  }
});
```

What improvements can be made to monitor PHP updates and automatically reload the page? Please provide an answer.